# do we have unsubscribe mail feature in openerp?

Tags: email, odoo, massmail, unsubscribe, lead

Do we have unsubscribe mail feature in openerp and if yes how to set it. I want to know when user receives mail from openerp can does it have that feature anywhere?

How does mass mail works exactly in case of leads and opportunities?

Any video reference or explaination will be helpful.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With the email there is link sent "click to unsubscribe" as you click on this, it leads you to unsubscribe page, where you see message "OK". Opt out is selected automatically in OpenERP,you dont have to select optout manually and no need they reply your email for ubsubscribe.As user3360821 has stated.

Answer (score 0):

I just asked the Open ERP Service if there is a possibility to unsubscribe the newsletter. That means, if you are sending Newsletters from the Open ERP System to your clients. My question was, if those companies can just unsubscribe these newsletters than. Followed you'll see the answer of Open ERP:
"The possibility for the companies to unsubscribe is to reply to your email. There is no button for them to unsubscribe, but you can stop the sending. Go to your customer form, click on "Extra Info" and then tick "Opt-out". He will be exempt of all new mass mailing. "